# matlab imdilate structural element origin confusion

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Consider the following operation:

```
 a =

     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0

 b=imdilate(a,[1,1;1,1])

b =

     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1
     0     0     1     1
```

The above result indicates the origin of the structual element is [2,2]. If the origin is floor((size([1,1;1,1])+1)/2)=[1,1] by the definition (http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/images/morph4.html)

```
b=
    1     1     0     0
    1     1     1     0
    0     1     1     0
    0     0     0     0
```

What's wrong with my understanding? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the origin is [1,1], but the origin is in the structuring matrix (2nd input), not the image matrix `a` (1st input).

Think about placing element [1,1] of your 2x2 structuring matrix on the non-zero values of `a` and you will see how the imdilate result is correct.

The Mathworks online help has a really nice [explanation of dilation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphology-fundamentals-dilation-and-erosion.html#f18-20972).

Comment: But without the rotation, the first element of b should be 1, because a(2,2)=1, and when you put [1,1;1,1] on a(1,1), it covers a(2,2), by definition b(1,1) will become 1.

Comment: There is no rotation. I'm not sure what you are thinking here. To get the result your describe, you need a 3x3 structuring matrix of ones.

Comment: But the idea is put the origin of the structural elements on top of each element of a(position x), find the maximum of the element in a covered by the non zero value of the structural element and put the result in position x to form b. And you see without rotation the result is wrong. I am wondering why matlab doesn't say this clear in the documentation.

Comment: No, it does not find the max. It only tests if the value of `a` under the origin of the structural element is non-zero.

Answer (score -1):

OK,Ｉｔｈｉｎｋ　Ｉ　ｈａｖｅ　ｆｏｕｎｄ　ｔｈｅ　ａｎｓｗｅｒ．
Similar to convolution, in dilation the structuring element is reflected through its center (rotated 180 degrees) before the max operation is applied.